# Dictionary regex

Tags: r

I have a function as follows:

```
HistolMacDescrip <- function(dataframe, MacroColumn) {
  dataframe <- data.frame(dataframe)

  # Column specific cleanup
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Dd]ictated by.*", "")
  # Conversion of text numbers to allow number of biopsies to be extracted
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Oo]ne", "1")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]ingle", "1")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Tt]wo", "2")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Tt]hree", "3")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ff]our", "4")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ff]ive", "5")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]ix", "6")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]even", "7")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ee]ight", "8")
  return(dataframe)
}
```

This strikes me as a bit inefficient. I have other functions that do a similar thing and I'd like to create one function instead that performs this kind of dictionary lookup, perhaps based on an external file that lists key values. Some of the keys will be regexes eg

```
key                                  value
bus|car|.*toy                     vehicle
\\d+\\s+mg                            dose
```

Is there a function that can do this kind of dictionary lookup function so that all I have to do is define the dictionary eg in a csv or something?

Comment: You may need a `fuzzy_join` after creating a key/val dataset with regex and the number to replace as 'val',

Comment: Suppose you have this lookup data frame consisting of `keys;values`. Do you want to apply *all* transformations to the data frame's columns, or is there one transformation per column?

Comment: @nate Yes I would apply all of the transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach

```
# Function
my_transform <- function (string, lookup) {
  new_string <- string
  vapply(1:nrow(lookup),
         function (k) {
           new_string <<- gsub(lookup$key[k], lookup$value[k], new_string)
           0L
         }, integer(1))
  new_string
}

# Results
# lookup table
lookup <- structure(list(key = c("bus|car|.*toy", "\\d+\\s+mg"), 
                         value = c("vehicle","dose")), 
                    row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

# string 1
string1 <- c('This car', '256 mg', '6536 \n mg')
my_transform(string1, lookup)
# [1] "This vehicle" "dose"         "dose" 

# # string 2
string2 <- c('This car is no toy', '256 mg', '6536 \n mg')
my_transform(string2, lookup)
# [1] "vehicle" "dose"    "dose"

# data frame
df <- data.frame(string1, string2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
matrix(my_transform(unlist(df), lookup), nrow(df), ncol(df))  
#      [,1]           [,2]     
# [1,] "This vehicle" "vehicle"
# [2,] "dose"         "dose"   
# [3,] "dose"         "dose"  
# or
vapply(1:ncol(df), 
       function (k) my_transform(.subset2(df, k), lookup),
       character(nrow(df)))
#      [,1]           [,2]     
# [1,] "This vehicle" "vehicle"
# [2,] "dose"         "dose"   
# [3,] "dose"         "dose"
```

So the idea is to store the substitutions in a table and then apply them. Using the above, it should be possible to obtain the desired output.

Note however issues can arise c.f. `string2[1]`: here you need to make sure what exactly is the desired output for such an instance.

Finally, two final points:

- `gsub` has other useful arguments such as `perl` (`TRUE or FALSE`) and `fixed` (`TRUE or FALSE`). These could be incorporated into the `lookup` table by for example adding columns labeled `perl, fixed, etc.`. This gives you more control.
- there a lot of useful `regex` functions (c.f. `?sub`): depending on your needs, you can either use or combine other functions.